# memory size grows rapidly in real time graph

Tags: wpf, graph, real-time

I am developing a real time graph application in WPF using normal Prism and MVVM concepts.

I have a ViewModel where i have the collection say GraphDotsCollection which keep on updating after every second. 100 points are added per seconds in it. This collection is binded with charting control in view.

Now as per the collection keeps on growing memory size also grows very fast and ultimately system out of memory exception raised.

I dont know how to get rid of this problem of memory.

I am using WPF tool kit.

Kindly help. Thanks a lot in advance.

D J

Comment: DJ, welcome to stack overflow. Here we show appreciation as well as letting future visitors know which answer correctly answered the question. Please accept the answers that solve your problem.

Comment: Also, in the case of this particular question, I see you have found the solution yourself. You can answer your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that you didn't commit this silly mistake, but just for a recheck.

Check your ViewModel. You must have declared some CLR Properties and those are binded to view control's (like :- your chart control)

You CLR Properties should like that

```
Public string YourCLRProp
{
      get { return _yourVariable;}
      set { _yourVariable=value;}
}
```

It Shouldn't like that

```
 Public string YourCLRProp
{
      get { return YourCLRProp;}
      set { YourCLRProp=value;}
}
```

Comment: public GraphDotsCollection GraphDotsCollection {} I think its correct...But one point how come the property declaration effect performance..?

Comment: What does a circular Property definition have to do with memory footprint? If the Property in your second example is ever set or read it will throw a StackOverflowException eventually but not OOM.

Comment: @ Jeetendra.Sharma property is fine. Edit :- The issue was in use of concurrent bags. I was using concurrent bag and for Notifications of collection update i was creating the new collection wrapper of same elements. So what i did, I created a new collection implementing ConcurrentBag and INotifyCollectionChanged. I cant paste my class code here. Some OOPS message is displayed. But problem is sorted out.